# Modifying a Template for

Tags: macros, templates, renewcommand

I'm using a [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/dictionary-template/pdztbwjxrpmz) for vocabulary and I need to modify it a little bit.

```latex
\newcommand{\entry}[5]{\markboth{#1}{#1}\textbf{#1}\ {/#2/}\ \textit{#3}\ $\bullet$\ {#4}}
% Defines the command to print each word on the page, \markboth{}{} prints the first word on the page in the top left header and the last word in the top right
```

Currently, the commend for each entry has the following structure; four arguments for the: word, pronunciation, classification and definition. For example

naive /naív/ Adjective • showinga lack of experience, wisdom, or judgment.

But many words have multiple meanings, so I would need to use lists inside the entry commend like this:

word /pronunciation/ *Noun* • meaning 1 • meaning 2
*Adjective* • meaing 1 meaning 2

Can anyone teach me how to modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that TeX is macro-based: it substitutes up to 10 patterns passed to a macro. I.e. you don't have a functional approach available in LaTeX, as far as I know. I.e. it's not that easy to deal with an unkonwn number of variables in advance.

So here is one way to do it, straight forward: split the `\newcommand` used in `overleaf` into several, and just call them one by one. There may be more elegant ways to do it.

So just call `\entry` (topic and pronounciation), `\type` (noun, adverb etc.) and one of the `\meanX` (depending of the number of meanings passed) macros. Use indenting to better follow more complex entries in the Latex-source-code. Don't forget to use an appropriate package to show correct phonetics/pronunciation: mine is just an indication.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
%\usepackage{}% use the appropriate package for phonetics/pronunciation

\newcommand{\entry}[2]{\textbf{#1}\ {/#2/}}
\newcommand{\type}[1]{\textit{#1}\ $\bullet$}
\newcommand{\meansA}[1]{{#1.}}
\newcommand{\meansB}[2]{{#1;}{ #2.}}
\newcommand{\meansC}[3]{{#1;}{ #2;}{ #3.}}

\begin{document}
    \entry{Right}{(rait)}
     \type{adjective}
      \meansA{morally good}
     \type{noun}
      \meansB{law}{justice} 
     \type{adverb}
      \meansC{direction}{directly}{correctly}
    
    \entry{Latex}{LAH-tekh}
    \type{abbreviation}
    \meansA{a typesetting program}
    \type{noun}
    \meansA{a milky fluid found in many plants}
\end{document}
```

**Result**:
[image: Result]

**P.S.**: It might be wise to use `\providecommand` instead.